# get aad users from department which contains using powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

I am looking the way how I can get all AAD users whom department contains specific string. I tried different methods, unfortunately without any results i.e.

```
Get-AzureADUser  | Where-Object {$_.Department -like "*xyz*"}
Get-AzureADUser | Where {$_.Department -contains '*xyz*'}
```

do you have any idea how it could be realized?

Thank you very much and regards!

Comment: Did you try Get-AzureADUser -Filter option as mentioned here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureaduser?view=azureadps-2.0

Comment: yep, but still I need to use somehow contains function and I do not know how to make it works

Comment: `-contains` is used to find something in an **array** of things, so that is of no use here. The `-Filter` uses [oData v3.0 filter statements](https://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-3-0/odata-version-3-0-core-protocol/#queryingcollections) and does not have an operator `like`. You could try `Get-AzureADUser -Filter "substringof('xyz',Department)`

Comment: Sorry, forgot the closing quote `"`

Comment: I had also tried this way but unfortunately it is resulted with Unsupported Query error message.

Comment: In that case, did you try adding `-All $true`? as in `Get-AzureADUser -All $true  | Where-Object {$_.Department -like "*xyz*"}`

Comment: Or `Get-AzureADUser -All $true -Filter "indexof(Department, 'xyz') ge 0"` maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get azure ad users of a department for a particular substring using the below command :

```
Get-AzureADUser -all $true | Where-Object {$_.Department -like "*ewD*"}
```

I have one user having test  department named example: newDev

[image]

Output :

[image]